# mongoDB : renaming column name in collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a schema that looks like

```
name: 
value:
pattern:
XUknown:
```

I have 2 million documents in this collection.

**Want**
- I want to rename the column name `XUknown` to `XString`, so that the schema looks like

```
name: 
value:
pattern:
XString:
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use a [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) modifier.

```
db.collection.update({}, {$rename: {'XUknown': 'XString'}}, false, true);
```

You might also refresh your knowledge of [update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).

Answer (score 6):

You can rename all the document by specify "Multi true" applicable to all the documents in the collection.

```
db.collection.update({}, {$rename: {'XUknown': 'XString'}}, {multi:true});
```